# Can't install .msu file in windows running in VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machines

This is to record a fix I found.

The issue:  running windows 7 in VMware player, when trying to install a .msu file from command line  z:\myFilename.msu,  got error message:

[image]

Here Z drive is mapped to a directory in the host PC.

Comment: For Stack Exchange sites like ServerFault.com, we ask that you record the question and the answer as separate posts.

Comment: You can also edit your posts... so you should fix this one.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it works fine if I copied the file to c: drive (by `copy z:\myFilename.msu c:\`) and install it from there.